# How to image a GCE instance with multiple persistent disks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

I'm looking for a way to snapshot/image a Google Cloud instance that uses multiple disks.  From what I've found so far, this does not seem to be supported, as I haven't seen a way to create an image that references more than one disk.  I'm surprised if this isn't available, as Amazon has had that functionality for a long time.  There you can simply issue a command to create an image from an existing instance, and it will automatically snapshot all disks attached to the instance and include them in the image, such that launching a new instance from the image creates all new disks based off the snapshots.  Is there a way to do this easily in GCE that I am missing, or does it just require custom scripting?

Answer (score 0):

The only option at present is to create snapshots/images of the VM Instance boot and the additional disks, however there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/74106832) so that this feature can be made available in the future. There is no ETA but any updates can be checked on this link above.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Aosoft,
           Not sure, if you already figured this out as its been a while. I came across it and I am using instance templates for this.

Need to create an image of each disk in VM and then group them as instance template. Use that instance template to provision new VMs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below command create image for the whole instance (all disks)

```
gcloud beta compute machine-images create instance-image ....
```

Detail can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/machine-images/create

P/s: It's different from the below command which create image for one disk only

```
gcloud compute images create ....
```

Hope that help...